# How to slice numbers from last index using angular pipe?

Tags: angular, pipe, slice

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'string-app',
  template: `
           <h3>String Example</h3>
       {{myStr | slice:3:7}} <br/>
       {{myStr | slice:3:-2}} <br/>
       {{myStr | slice:6}} <br/>
       {{myStr | slice:-6}} <br/>          
         ` 
})
export class StringSlicePipeComponent {
    myStr: string = "abcdefghijk";
} 

output.
    String Example
    defg
    defghi
    ghijk
    fghijk
```

In my case, my string will be always ending with 3 digits.How to slice those 3 digits

Example

```
my string : abcdef123, ahdvvhvhv456
```

i want to slice 123 and 456 from the end. How to do this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To remove the last 3 characters from the string, you can use:

```
{{ myStr | slice:0:-3 }}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bkjkch) for a demo.

---

On the other hand, if you want to show only the last 3 characters of the string, you can use:

```
{{ myStr | slice:-3 }}
```

Comment: Just `slice:-3` is required.

Comment: @ChrisW. - It depends if she wants to show the last 3 digits, or if she wants to show the string without these 3 digits.

Comment: That's my penance for speed reading on a Friday, you're correct :D

Comment: @ChrisW. Your comment is what I came looking for, thanks! +1